# Why can't I import Pandas and Matplotlib in Pycharm from Anaconda, when it works with Spyder?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pycharm, anaconda

I installed Anaconda to start using pandas and matplotlib. However, Anaconda did not enable me to use them in the Pycharm IDE. I opened a command prompt and typed pip install pandas but it threw an error. I uninstalled everything: Anaconda, Pycharm, Python itself... and reinstalled everything. That didn't help at all. After installing Pycharm through Anaconda, it threw the same error: `No Module Named 'pandas'` I then tried the Spyder IDE in Anaconda, and importing pandas and matplotlib works perfectly. However, I then opened the Pycharm IDE in Anaconda, and when I run the same code it throws the same old error - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'` Does anyone know why this is happening?  Why can't I import pandas and matplotllib in Pycharm when it works just fine in Spyder?

Comment: Are you sure that you use the same python? Edit your questions and add logs of the commands to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you are not using the same python interpreter (and therefore virtual environment) and therefore pycharm is not able to import the packages simply because they are not there.
Try to run this both in your `pycharm` and `spyder` console:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

and check if their path is exactly the same.

Comment: That's exactly the issue.  I checked and their paths are completely different.

Comment: What I advise you to do is to change the interpreter of pycharm to what spyder is using (check this link https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/#:~:text=Configuring%20a%20conda%20environment%20in%20PyCharm,-In%20the%20Settings&text=Select%20Preferences.,dialog%20box%2C%20select%20Conda%20Environment.)

Comment: @CurryChurner choose it as answer if it helped )

Comment: I was able to change the path, and wasn't sure if I successfully changed the interpreter.  It still didn't work, so I uninstalled everything, deleted all files associated with all deleted applications, and then re-installed everything through Anaconda.  Now, the original problem remains in Pycharm: **Module Not Found Error: No module named 'pandas'**

Comment: I've discovered that the original problem is different.  This is the real problem:  Anaconda.  When I try to open the base (root) environment that contains all of the packages, it doesn't give me the option of opening it with Pycharm.  It gives me only 4 options:  1.open Terminal,  2.open with Python, 3.open with IPython, 4.open with Jupyter Notebook.  I can launch Pycharm independently, but it creates a new environment that doesn't include any of the Anaconda packages.

Comment: Did you try changing the interpreter in pycharm?